# SSRS Division Rounding

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've got a report that uses a DateDiff/Minute function in the Dataset, then divides that number by 60 in an expression in a report column, to give me hours as a decimal, in addition to minutes. However, that expression is rounding down to the nearest whole number.

For example 521 minutes divided by 60 will render as "8.00" instead of "8.68."

I do have the text box format set to a number with two decimal places. I do not have any rounding parameters in the expression. It's just "=Fields!ColumnName.value / 60"

Not sure what else to check here to make it round properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops = replaced "\" with "/" and it works fine.